# Expression for blindly following rules

Tags: expression, idiomaticity

Is there any expression which denotes either

- The act of blindly and dogmatically following rules/instructions without regard for the practicality of doing so (For example, this would be an epithet which someone may use to refer to another person who reprimands him/her for riding a bike on a sidewalk, which is presumably not disturbing anyone other than the person reprimanding the rider)
- A person who does the above?

The closest examples I can come up with are *Spießer*, *Spaßbremse* or someone who is *kleinkariert*. Still, none of these directly denote the above behaviour but, instead, the people described by these terms might do the above (but not necessarily so).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

German doesn't really have strong terms for persons behaving like you describe, but rather for the behaviour as such.

*Dienst nach Vorschrift* is one (following rules by the book in the sense of never do more than the book requires you to, well knowing that is not the right thing),

*Blinder Gehorsam* another one that doesn't necessarily imply you should know better as the above.

*Beamtenmentalität* would be a nice one targeting the mindset, and

*Kadavergehorsam* is an even stronger term (maybe the strongest the language has) for slavish obedience to rules. This one has an interesting history going back to Ignatius of Loyola (Founder of the Jesuit Order) back in the middle ages describing "zombie-like" following of orders (He apparently considered a virtue). Interestingly, this term seems to be of Spanish origin ;)

Krümelkacker, Erbsenzähler, Pingel (from "pingelig") would be softer terms than the above.

Someone actively *searching for disobedience* in other people's activities can be called a *Blockwart* which used to be the Nazi term for party members inaugurated to monitor, follow and give notice of "mis-behaviour" amongst their direct neighbors, i.e. denunciate (Today may be considered a strong insult)

Comment: "Dienst nach Vorschrift" ist eine elaborierte Form zivilen Ungehorsams, bei dem man die Regeln (z.B. Sicherheitsvorschriften) so pedantisch auslegt, dass der ordentliche Betrieb nicht mehr möglich ist. Blinder Gehorsam/Kadavergehorsam bezeichnet eine Haltung gegenüber Vorgesetzten/Institutionen, nicht gegenüber einem Regelwerk. Auch der Blockwart ist typischerweise von Vasallentreue geprägt, nicht von buchstabengetreuer Pedanterie, die ja zur Dysfunktionalität tendiert.

Comment: Bei "Dienst nach Vorschrift" bin ich nicht ganz einig mit den Beweggründen, die du unterstellst - Das *muss* nicht unbedingt ziviler Ungehorsam sein, sondern kann u.U. auch nur Lustlosigkeit sein, die jemanden dazu bringt, genau soviel zu tun, wie minimal vorgeschrieben ist. Und mit der originalen Begrifflichkeit des *Kadavergehorsams* hat Herr von Loyola durchaus *auch* das Regelwerk des christlichen Glaubens und nicht nur die Institution Kirche gemeint. Für ihn war das nämlich dasselbe.

Comment: Ähnliches gilt auch für den Blockwart - Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen "Vasallentreue" und "Regelwerk" innerhalb der Nazi-Organisation nicht so sehen wie du - Das Eine war im Anderen festgeschrieben. Die Blockwarte wurden durchaus auf "gesetzlicher" Grundlage installiert und hatten ihr Berufsdenunziantentum auch nach einem offiziell ausgegebenen Regelwerk auszuüben.

Comment: 1968 war den Fluglotsen als Beamten das Streiken untersagt, und so verlegten sie sich auf diese Form des Arbeistkampfes und prägten den Begriff http://www.bazonbrock.de/werke/detail/?id=2769&sectid=2559 . Ein Blick zu Google-Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dienst+nach+Vorschrift&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDienst%20nach%20Vorschrift%3B%2Cc0 zeigt, dass damit der Begriff geboren war. Der Blockwart ist, wie Du selbst schreibst, in erster Linie ein Denunziant. P.S.: Du musst m. Namen ben., wenn ich eine Nachricht bekommen soll.

Comment: This answer helped me the most, but all were excellent; It's a shame I can accept only one...

Answer (score 6):

`Korinthenkacker` is described as a pernickety, pedantic person. It literally translates to `someone who shits currants`.

`Pedant` is a pedantic person (female: `Pedantin`) and `Pedanterie` the behaviour of that person.

Maybe `Paragrafenreiter` fills your needs, is someone who strictly follows the rules.

Comment: *Paragraphenreiter* is the one we want. +1

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the terms given by tofro, I could offer "regelhörig" (*following and believing in rules no matter whether they make sense or not*) or "Regelhörigkeit" (*the property of being "regelhörig"*). (There is no corresponding noun for a person who has this property.)

Answer (score 2):

To the given Answers one could add:

Formalist ... formalist

Tüpflischisser ... (used in Swiss and Südbaden) for [*Korintenkacker*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korinthenkacker)

[I-Tüpferlreiter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/i_Tuepferl_Reiter) ... is a synonym for *Pedant* from Austrian Slang.

hyperkorrekt ... hypercorrect

Übergenau ... meticulous = one could also say more then exact/accurate/precise

kleinlich ... micrological

akribisch ... painstaking

peinlich genau ... minute

So far all the given expressions are more or less synonyms!

mit Scheuklappen ... a person "with blinders": a person who doesn't turn neither right nor left and just goes ahead following the given instruction/direction!

Comment: @errantlinguist ... i think some answers here are much better explained then mine. Once a diversity of answers is possible it will always be hard to choose one as the accepted. And especially when it comes to linguistic expressions it would be hard to give an overarching answer